# Question about uniform convergence?

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if $a > 0$, then the convergence of $(\frac{x}{x+n})$ is uniform on the interval $[0, a]$ but not uniform on the interval $[0,\infty)$.

Let $f_n(x) = \frac{x}{x+n}$ and $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$.

I know that $(\frac{x}{x+n})$ converges pointwise to $0$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$ (this was the first part of this question).

By following the example in my textbook, I did the following:

Let $n_k = k$ and let $x_k = k$, then:

$f_{nk}(x_k) = \frac{1}{2}$

It follows that:

$|f_{nk}(x_k) - f(x_k)| = |\frac{1}{2} - 0| = \frac{1}{2}$

But this shows that the convergence is NOT uniform.  I'm not sure how to split it up into the two intervals, and I'm not sure why or how to show that it does converge uniformly for $[0,a]$.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You are along the right path for showing that the convergence is not uniform on $[0,\infty)$. Perhaps you just need to make it more rigorous by negating the definition of uniform convergence.

To show uniform convergence on $[0,a]$, consider expressing $\frac{x}{x+n}$ as $1-\frac{n}{x+n}$. From here, apply the definition of uniform convergence to prove the result.

EDIT (in response to the comment below)

You are right, the choice of $k$ and $x$ is somewhat arbitrary. It depends on the behavior of the function, and though practice you'll get an idea of what to look for.

We have that $f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}$ is not uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$. Let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$. For each $n\geq 1$, let $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$. Then $f_n(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{n\frac{1}{n}}{1+n^2\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Therefore, $\exists\epsilon>0$ $\forall n\geq 1$ $\exists x_n\in[0,\infty)$ such that $f_n(X_n)\geq \epsilon$, negating the definition of uniform convergence.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  Another question - I chose the values of x_k and n_k somewhat arbitrarily.  Is there a good strategy to know how to choose them?  For example, if f_n(x) = nx / (1+(n^2)(x^2)), it doesn't seem like choosing k for both x_k and n_k would work.

Comment: I made an edit in the my original response.

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint}$:   $\displaystyle0\le x\le a\implies \frac{x}{x+n}\le\frac{a}{a+n}<\frac{a}{n}<\epsilon$ if $n>\frac{a}{\epsilon}$, so you can use this to show uniform convergence on $[0,a]$.

As you have, $f_{n}(n)=\frac{1}{2}$ for all n, so this shows that the convergence on $[0,\infty)$ cannot be uniform (since there is no N corresponding to $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$).